# iPhone - core data crashing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

I have two entities: products and bundles. Each one has its class. A product can be in multiple bundles.

Entities are defined like this:

```
PRODUCTS
name, string
number, integer 16
fromBundle = to-many relationship to product

BUNDLE
name, string
number, integer 16
product = to-many relationship to fromBundle
```

Products were assigned to bundle like this:

```
// suppose bundle 1 is composed of products 1, 2, 3 and 4.
NSArray *myProd = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
    nil];

int bundleNumber = 1;
NSString *bundleName = @"My Bundle";
Bundle *aBundle = nil;

NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Bundle" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(number == %d)", bundleNumber];
NSError *error = nil;
aBundle = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];

// as the bundle does not exist, this will run
if (!error && !aBundle) {
    aBundle = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Bundle" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    aBundle.string = bundleName;
    aBundle.Number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:bundleNumber];

    for (NSNumber *umNum in myProd) {

            // the product with number = aNum is retrieved... yes it is valid at this point 
            Product *oneProduct = [ProductWithNumber:umNum inManagedObjectContext:context];
            NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [oneProduct mutableSetValueForKey:@"fromBundle"];
            [mutableSet addObject:aBundle];
    }
// Save the context.
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}

// everything is fine at this point.
```

Now I wish to retrieve a list of all products that belong to a specific bundle...

To do that, I am using this method on Bundle class

```
+ (NSArray *)ProductsInBundle:(Bundle*)aBundle inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSArray *all = nil;


    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Products" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(fromBundle == %@)", aBundle];

    NSError *error = nil;
    all = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; // crashes here

    return all;
}
```

it crashes on the assigned line on the last method with the message "to-many key not allowed here" when I try to do this

```
NSArray *allProductsInBundle = [Bundle ProductsInBundle:aBundle inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

aBundle is valid at this point.

Comment: Is the 'Tabuleiros' here just a copy/paste mistake for your question here? EDIT: Looks like you already fixed it ^_^

Comment: How are you creating the Bundle class? (i.e. the actual class header and implementation, are you having Core Data generate that for you?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your predicate is wrong. You don't have a bundle property, but a fromBundle property.

If it is really fromBundle, then your predicate should be:

```
equest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(fromBundle == %@)", aBundle];
```

EDIT:

If you are trying to do operations on to-many relationships then you'll need to use the aggregate functions for the predicate. I think for your case you'll want the `IN` operation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891

Comment: sorry about that, it was a typo, as I had to modify the code to post it here, to make it more clear. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing a fetch when you have a relationship?  That is heavy and expensive.  Just request the products for the bundle via

```
[aBundle valueForKey:@"product"];
```

The fetch is unnecessary and forces a disk hit when you probably don't need one.  Core Data most likely has the `product` relationship cached.

Also, when you are assigning a product to a bundle you do not need to get a mutable set.  Just set the bundle into the product via:

```
[product setValue:bundle forKey:@"fromBundle"];
```

Core Data will manage the other side of the relationship.